# Keep LinearLayout gone when reusing View it's in for ListView

Tags: android, listview

As the title says, I have a `LinearLayout` that I use as a part of an item of `ListView`. When I click on item I need to change visibility of its `LinearLayout` from `View.GONE` to `View.VISIBLE` (or vice versa).

My problem is that when I click the first item (so now its layout is visible), and than scroll the list down, the item that reuses the first item appears to have its Layout's visibility set to `View.VISIBLE` too, exactly as the first item did, although it supposed to be `View.GONE`. The rest of the displayed items that don't reuse the first one works as they're supposed to.

I clearly understand why that's happening, and I guess I need to store visibility of the `LinearLayout` for every single item in my `ListView` (not only currently displayed) and then use it in my `getView()` method. Do you guys have any idea how do I do it?

Some code from my activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView alarmClocksListView;
        ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClocksList;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            alarmClocksList = new ArrayList<>();
            alarmsArrayAdapter = new AlarmsArrayAdapter(this, alarmClocksList);
            alarmClocksListView.setAdapter(alarmsArrayAdapter);
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            //some code
            alarmClocksList.add(new AlarmClock());
            alarmsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your adapters code and your activity code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, I found a solution. What I basicly did was to add a boolean to the class that stores data I display in my `ListView` (since every item has its own object with data it seems to be a good idea to put layout's visibility there). Than in my `getView()` method I just retrieve that value and use it as visibility for my layout. When a `View` is being clicked I handle it accordingly, changing visibility inside of the appropriate object. I also use a button for changing visibility from `View.VISIBLE` to `View.GONE` (for those who are interested what is that button for).

Here is my adapter:

```
public class AlarmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClockArrayList;
    private Context context;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView whenAlarmRings;
        RelativeLayout additionalPanel;
        Button doneButton;
    }

    public AlarmsArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClocks) {
        super(context, -1, alarmClocks);
        alarmClockArrayList = alarmClocks;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        AlarmClock alarmClock = alarmClockArrayList.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_clock_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.whenAlarmRings = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.whenAlarmRings);
            holder.additionalPanel = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.additionalPanel);
            holder.doneButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        if (alarmClock.isViewExpanded == true) {
            holder.additionalPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.whenAlarmRings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.additionalPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.whenAlarmRings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        setListeners(holder, alarmClock, convertView);
        holder.whenAlarmRings.setText(alarmClock.whenAlarmRings);

        for (int i = 0; i < AlarmClock.DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++)
            holder.days[i].setChecked(alarmClock.weekDaysState[i]);
        return convertView;
    }

    private void setListeners(final ViewHolder holder, final AlarmClock alarmClock, final View convertView) {
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.whenAlarmRings.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    holder.whenAlarmRings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.additionalPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    alarmClock.isViewExpanded = true;
                    //convertView.setClickable(false);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.whenAlarmRings.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    holder.whenAlarmRings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.additionalPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    alarmClock.isViewExpanded = false;
                    //convertView.setClickable(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my class that stores data:

```
public class AlarmClock {
    public static final boolean LIST_ITEM_IS_EXPANDED_BY_DEFAULT = true;
    public String whenAlarmRings;
    public boolean isViewExpanded;

    public AlarmClock() {
        this.isViewExpanded = LIST_ITEM_IS_EXPANDED_BY_DEFAULT;
        this.whenAlarmRings = "SomeDay";
    }
}
```